# What is the best way to select a rows by comparing ENUM and SET columns

Tags: mysql, enums

I mean if any table consist of ENUM or SET typed column and I will make the query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabname` WHERE `enum_field` = 'case1' OR `enum_field` = 'case2'
```

Will it be efficient?
Or the engine will convert number stored in enum_field to string, compare it to the pattern (in my example - case1 and case2)?
What is the most efficient way to use such columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you provided above is correct.
The database engine will convert the strings in your query into numeric indexes, which will be used when searching the table.

According to the **[mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)**, you can also query directly by numeric index, but this can sometimes have unexpected results, particularly if any of your enum string values are numeric.

So assuming "case1" has index 1, and "case2" has index 2, you could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabname` WHERE `enum_field` = 1 OR `enum_field` = 2
```